# Switch for battery device

Tags: batteries, switches

I have a motion activated circuit build with a spring switch (sw‑18020p) and powered by a CR2030 coin cell. Every time i "shake" the circuit, it turns ON for some seconds to grab some sensors readings and then turns OFF. Everything is insulated with epoxy so i don't have access to the components after i install battery.

I'm looking for some kind of circuitry to prevent the device to turn ON, like for storing purpose. I was thinking of a reed switch inside and a magnet outside, so if i remove magnet it operate normally and if i put magnet back, i could store it without activating by accident.
The problem with reed switch is they are made of glass and break very easy, so i was looking for something more robust.

Anyone have a better idea?

Comment: Having encapsulated the reed sw in epoxy, is it really still all that fragile?

Comment: I think you'll find the reed switches surprising tough. I agree with Brian that once potted they are unlikely to suffer. Your going to need NC type which aren't as common.

Comment: What about a micro power hall sensor/switch?

Comment: Stefan: good point, it seems more robust than reed switch. I'm going to make a test to see if it works

Answer (score 1):

reed switches require precise alignment of the electrodes for correct operation glass is an ideal matrerial as is it rigid, non-coductive, and non-magnetic.

If embedding in epoxy does not harden the reed switch enough (they are pretty tough to start with) pad the reed switch by placing it inside a tube of silicone before encapsulating it.

Comment: Well, i have to make a test to see if is tough enough. I'll also try hall sensor to see if works.

Thanks guys for the help.